# Client wants to hire a full time employee under my company/contract

Tags: contracts, pay-rate, remote, subcontracting

So here's my situation. A client hired me for a part time job and we signed under my contract. Now they want me to go and find someone who can work full time on the same job I do. However I'm not sure as to how they want to proceed regarding the rate. I'm very careful discussing the rate because I don't want to show the client that I'm most concerned with the pay than the work at hand. Also I'm not sure as how to approach this situation as this is my first time doing this kind of arrangement.

It is also worth mentioning that the client and I are from different countries, they are from US and I'm from the other side of the world. Also since they are the ones asking for a full time worker under my company it is understandably a transparent transaction, meaning they are aware that I'm not using anyone to do work under my name, they are well aware the someone is doing full time work for them.

**EDIT**
They specifically asked "how much would it cost to hire a full time person under my company". Sounds to me that they want a different rate for that person.

So now here are my questions:

1. What rate should I offer them? The job is fairly easy and can be done by anyone who is computer savvy. Is it fair to me and the client that I stick with the same price per hour? I'm afraid that I would lose them if I do stick with the same rate.

   Or should I just use my rate and just give a percentage of it to the person I'm hiring?
2. Should I let my employee communicate with the client directly? I'm afraid that they might remove me from the equation since I won't be doing much of the work and only supervise.
3. Do you guys think I should modify the contract between me and the client and create another one for the person I'm going to hire?
4. Lastly, is it rude to ask about the rate we're going to use, either my rate or the newbie's rate? Or is it fine to be straight-forward with people from US?

Comment: Would this full-time person be an employee in your company or a freelancer where you are the middle-man?

Comment: That is what I want to also ask with the client. But what do you think is the best arrangement that will benefit me? Sorry for being selfish but I have been working with the client for over months and take note that I need to transfer my knowledge to this employee/freelancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct approach depends on several aspects:

1) Will this person be employed by you?

If yes, you should be compensated for the bureaucracy that follows having employees. If not, will you bill the client and have the full-timer bill you a bit less?

Bear in mind, having an employee means you are responsible for finding work for this person when this project ends. In your situation, I would prefer someone who is already a freelancer and have them bill you - and then you bill the client a bit more.

You could also take a one-time payment for findng the full-timer and have them bill the client directly - but that could remove you from the equation altogether.

2) Maintaining an ongoing relationship with the client:

Two scenarios: If the project scope is well-defined, you could go for a fixed-price contract. If it isn't, you should negotiate two hourly rates: One for the full-timer and one for whatever hours you are needed managing or delivering; he latter rate being higher than the former.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this person will be employed by me and I want to maintain the relationship with the client since I need this extra income. I don't have experience managing others but I can learn. So the follow up question is how should I be compensated? Am I just going to be billed for the time it took to check the deliverables? Shouldn't I get a certain percentage from my employees' salary?

Comment: OK. I've edited my answer so it's hopefully more specific to your case

Comment: Thank you that is more spot on. But I have another concern: if I'm going to hire a freelancer and they are allowed to communicate with the client wouldn't that remove me from the equation eventually? Also let's say I wasn't needed to manage for over a week because the employee was able to deliver 100% without my help, wouldn't that be unfair for me not receiving any salary?

Comment: Only you can answer those questions. Your approach depends on how needed YOU are; will you still be valuable to the client even with the full-timer there? If you believe so (and the client agrees), you should be payed for 'project management' in some capacity. If not, you should negotiate a one-time payoff and an hourly rate for any other future tasks